# jQuery autocomplete remote JSON datasource not returning data

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I've been working forever on this, and searched through all the other examples and still can't seem to figure it out, trying to use jquery ui autocomplete, first time trying to put this all together. Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#search-title").autocomplete({
    source: function ( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/include/autocomplete",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                        term: request.term      
                    },
            success: function (data) {
                response( $.map( data.stuff, function ( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name,
                        value: item.name
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
        window.location = ui.item.value;
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Checking out the Response in Firebug, I think I'm getting properly formatted JSON here:

```
{"stuff":[ {"label" : "Dragon", "value" : "http://site.com/animal/firebreathers"}] }
```

But for some reason it's not hooking up. After I hit the minLength a small, empty box will open beneath the search field but nothing will be in there.

**UPDATE:** When I add "alert(item);" in the response call, I get a window that says "The page at site.com says: object Object" -- could this be the issue?

Comment: Isn't item an object? Have you tried accessing parameters in item such as item.value?

Comment: Thank you!! thanks to you I finally have my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out, thanks to that hint comment under my question.

In the return, which I copied from the Jquery UI site, i had:

```
label: item.name,
value: item.name
```

Changing that to:

```
label: item.label,
value: item.value
```

Solved my struggle with jQuery. I have no idea if this is good practice, but it finally works!

Answer (score 0):

try using jsonp instead of json in datatype.